# Powershell command to get lower directory

Tags: powershell-extensions

I currently have a script that puts a file in a directory the website but would rather create it in the Data directory.

The powershell script has the below:

```
$FilePath = $AppPath + "Temp_files\MyLists\"
```

Current Result, file into directory "D:/inetpub/mysite.com/Website/Temp_files/MyLists/"

Preferred Result, file into directory:  "D:/inetpub/mysite.com/Data/Temp_files/MyLists/"

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Are you expecting the script to run from within the context of Sitecore or are you running this directly in the instance of Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume your question is requesting how to do this using Sitecore PowerShell Extensions.

There are a number of builtin variables that SPE generates. I recommend you make use of those before using the static variables with a fully-qualified namespace.

**Example:** The following uses the variable `$SitecoreDataFolder`.

```powershell
$filepath = "$($SitecoreDataFolder)\Temp_Files\MyLists"
```

### Reference

[List of variables](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items/variables)

Comment: Correct on the Sitecore PowerShell Extensions.  Thanks for the answer and the link to the Reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can try in this way:

```
 $dataFolder = [Sitecore.Configuration.Settings]::DataFolder
 $tempFolder = $dataFolder + "\Temp_files\MyLists\"
```

Comment: Thx, I added a "\" in front of the "Temp_files\MyLists\" so it needs to be "\Temp_files\MyLists\"